# JCE - Java 7...?

Tags: java, encryption, java-7, jce, ssha

I've installed `JDK 7`. Which already contains the following JARs:

```
local_policy
US_export_policy
```

But when I start my application, I was facing `JCE error`. So I googled and downloaded `JDK 7` JCE from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html).

My doubt is, when `JDK 7` already has `JCE JARs`, why should I specifically download the same `JCE JARs` and replace the existing `JCE JARs` again..??

**Edit:**

I am using `SSHA` encryption.

Log:

```
java.security.invalidkeyexception: illegal key size
java.lang.illegalstateexception: cipher not initialized
```

Comment: "JCE error"... Are there any more details? Like a stacktrace?

Comment: you probably have to get the "Unlimited Strength" policy files and install them in your JRE. The default is crippled due to import restrictions in some countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downloaded files are not *the same*.

Basically the named `.jar` files only contain property files which enable/disable some cryptography functions. This is because of several different export/import regulations in different countries.

You could also modify this files by yourself and enable/disable some cryptography functions for your application.

Comment: They have same names, but are different. You must [override them with the files from the JCE](http://fix-it-issues.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-install-jce-java-cryptography.html).

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is, when JDK 7 already has JCE JARs, why should I specifically download the same JCE JARs and replace the existing JCE JARs again..??

No.  Or at least, not without understanding what the JCE error means.

If you showed us the error messages / stacktraces, maybe we could help you with that.

---

**UPDATE**

Those errors look like problems in your code rather than in JCE.

1. SSHA stands for Salted SHA.  SSH / SSHA are secure hash schemes, not an encryption schemes.  Moreover, you won't find a JCE provider for SSHA ... because it is *really* just a variation on SHA where you add a "salt" to the input that you are hashing.
2. The "illegal key size" exception looks like you are misusing one of the API methods.

If you showed us the **code** that throws the exceptions ... and the **full** stacktraces ... we could give you a more definite answer.  But I'm convinced that replacing the JCE JARs will make no difference.